when we say a memory controller does it mean the component that manages communication between the RAM and the processor only?
In general what does a memory controller mean and is it only the bridge between the processor and RAM or also for other memory devices?
Can't clearly understand if a memory controller is only for a processor and RAM or also for other memory devices within the system

It's usually only the device that controls the RAM/NVRAM DIMMs. But each platforms has its set of implied meanings, generally speaking it should be clear from the context.

Memory controller generally refers to the hardware component of a processor that handles communication between the processor and main memory (e.g., RAM), non-volatile memory (e.g., NVRAM), or graphics memory.
There is also a Cache controller that manages cache memory.
Here is a very high-level overview of the process
Following a CPU request, the MMU translates the virtual address to a physical address, and the cache Controller checks to see if the data is in a cache. If not, it requests the data from the memory controller using the translated address provided by the MMU. The memory controller retrieves the data and sends it to the cache controller, which saves the data in a cache and sends it to the CPU.

The memory controller also has to accept requests for memory access from non-CPU devices, like the GPU or DMA from PCIe bus-master devices.  In modern CPUs, the DRAM controller is normally built-in to the same silicon chip as the CPU cores, which is why we call it a SoC (System on Chip).  In the diagram in https://www.anandtech.com/show/3922/intels-sandy-bridge-architecture-exposed/4 IMC is the Integrated Memory Controller.  Each core has its own MMU, but the memory controller is shared by the whole chip.
